# Ajax parse inline json variable of URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

solely for test purposes I want to pass an inline json file in my AJAX call, it seems the parameter URL has to be a URL, is there a way round this so I can parse an inline json file through the call, the current code is as follows, but doesn't work:

```
var jsonfile =[      
        {
        "id" : "look1",
        "image" : "http://images.domain.com/img.jpg",
        "headline" : "UN DÍA EN MÓNACO"
        }
        ,
        {
        "id" : "look2",
        "image" : "http://images.domain.com/img.jpg",
       "headline" : "UN DÍA EN MÓNACO"
        },
.......

    $.ajax({
        url: jsonfile,
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        cache : false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(source){
            data = source;
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Failed to load content");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't think of any useful application for this. What's the point of making an ajax call to data that is already there?

Comment: I will eventually be calling an external json file but at the moment I don't have access to it.

Comment: Ajax is to "Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request." so no, I dont think you can do it on an 'inline file'. Also your inline file isnt a file, its a variable. Why not just use the data as you have it and then once you have access to the file, then implement your ajax

Comment: If you want to test your success function, just call it with the variable as parameter.

Comment: how can I do that sorry @GeraldSchneider?